# vector of const ref to vector<vector<long>> assignment does not compile

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++17

We can't make a vector of references.

See already answered question.

Comment: You cannot have a vector of references the same way you cannot have an array of references.

Comment: Just like you can't have a reference to a reference you also cannot have a container of references,

Comment: I suspect that you believe that C++ references are like references in some other languages, like Java, C#, or Python. The only thing they really have in common is the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector` doesn't support reference. you might use `std::reference_wrapper` or pointers instead.